# Cordova app is rejected vulnerabilities issue

Tags: cordova, android-security

Our app in latest version of cordova 5 but our app is rejected and reason is below:

Apache Cordova
The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1. For more information about the vulnerabilities, and for guidance on upgrading Apache Cordova, please see https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html. For other technical questions about Apache Cordova, please post to https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions and use the tags "android-security" and "cordova."

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: make sure your app doesn't have old code (cordova.jar, cordova.js)

Comment: We have checked there is latest cordova.js

Comment: you don't have to add any cordova.js, it's generated and copied to it's place

Comment: What is the package name of the app?

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this in case someone else falls into the same trap: I got this error, and it persisted after upgrading to the latest version of Cordova (6.0.0). I upgraded my platforms and all of my plugins, but the error persisted. Eventually I discovered an old, forgotten and unused backup copy of cordova.js buried deep in a subfolder. Although this old file was not being called by my application, Google's text search was finding it and failing my app. File deleted, bug fixed!

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to update cordova globaly on your machine:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Then you should update & build android platform in your app:

```
cordova platform update android
cordova build android
```

To check if the version has been upgraded run the command:

```
cordova platform
```

---

For more help, follow the below guide from apache cordova site:

[This guide shows how to modify Android projects to upgrade from older versions of Cordova.](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide/platforms/android/upgrading.html)

---

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. Simple fix: make sure cordova is updated in your source code, start an entirely new project on google play (name it something else), and submit the updated app.